# Search shows all products with layer navigation

Tags: magento, layered-navigation, advanced-search

I am trying to fix a bug on advanced search page.
The issue is if i search for some keys say "red" then all the results shows up. ex: for red it shows up 62 results in single page, even though the pagination limit is there. Pagination set to show 27 products per page. But still the page shows all 62 products.
It means, initially the pagination is not working.

I did some research on this and found that layer navigation is causing the problem. I tried to remove the layer navigation from the settings(catalogsearch.xml) file and tried, then the search was very fast and pagination was also working fine. I need both pagination and layer navigation.

Here is my code for advanced search block.

```
<catalogsearch_advanced_result translate="label">
    <label>Advanced Search Result</label>
    <update handle="page_two_columns_right" />
    <!-- Mage_Catalogsearch -->
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>javascript/jquery.history.js</script></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/searchresult-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.vertnav</name></action>

        <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" template="catalogsearch/layer/view.phtml"/>

    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_result" name="catalogsearch_advanced_result" template="catalogsearch/advanced/result.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" />
                    <action method="addAjax"><ajax>true</ajax></action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>27</limit></action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>54</limit></action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>75</limit></action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>100</limit></action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
            <action method="setListOrders"/>
            <action method="setListModes"/>
            <action method="setListCollection"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```

Please suggest why the pagination doesnt work in first load. Later the pagination works fine.

Comment: I have fixed the initial pagination issue. But still unable to fix the layer navigation performance. Its still slow.

Comment: $this->drawOpenCategoryItem() this function is making the search very slow. Its there in /app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Advanced/Navigation.php. it takes 1 category, checks for if any child category is there or not... if there again goes into loop and repeats for others in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way.

You can set the attribute status "visible in advanced search" (in attribute administration).

Then you only need change the template/catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml file, placing inside the form tag this html: `<input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="1"/>`

And finaly you need remove "status" field from attribute fields, placing after open foreach this code: `<?php if($_attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'status') continue; ?>`